Open Modelica Temperature Controlled Valve
I've tried to build a new modelica model representing a valve that could be controlled in temperature. Specifically my goal is to create a valve that could result open, for pipe's temperature before the valve, under a specific temperature setpoint value(t_setpoint). So I've created a new simple model made up by a source->boundary(m,t); the first dynamic pipe(pipe1); the valve(valve); the second dynamic pipe; and the last buondary(p, T) to complete the model. I've settled an if condition to manage the valve opening(valve.opening = if pipe1.mediums[3].T < valve.t_setpoint then 1 else 0;). Where "mediums[3].T" is the temperature measurated in the section of the pipe concerning the region of the last volume of pipe1 just before the valve(in the case we have divided pipe1 in 3 volume).I've used to test the model medium=standardwater IF97. Is there any other possibility to create that type of valve to simulate it also for higher temperature on the input in the initial boundary?
I've try diffucult to compile the model even if there are no errors in the code and sometimes(expecially for high temperature input or for long simulation times) the compilation stopped.

Regarding "sometimes(...) the compilation stopped.": This sounds like chattering (see MBE on state events) is the issue with the simulation not advancing - given I understood that correctly.
I would try to start modelling graphically. Probably from Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatingSystem by replacing the handle with some control, likely including Modelica.Blocks.Logical.Hysteresis which should ease the issues with chattering.

Thanks, i have to add the Hysteresis block in the upper input  of the valve or implement it modifyng the script code? Regarding the model to simulate the valve do you think  i'ved follow a correct way or there are other solutions?

(1) I would suggest to add the hysteresis in the graphical view, so add the block and connect the output to the valve.
(2) It is difficult to judge if a way of modeling is correct. If it works and is simple to understand, it likely is fine. For beginners it is often better to use pre-defined models via the graphical layer...
